# Extract specific data from a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
| Start| End | Distance|
|------|-----|---------|
| A    | B   |       10|
| A    | C   |       11|
| A    | D   |       12|
| B    | C   |       13|
| B    | D   |       14|
| C    | D   |       15|
```

I need to extract the distance values based on a list that is shown below:

```
start_end_list = [A, B, B, C, C]
```

Therefore, the distance value that is extracted will be converted into another data frame that is the combination of Start and End data like shown below:

```
| Start| End | Distance|
|------|-----|---------|
| A    | B   |       10|
| A    | B   |       10|
| A    | C   |       11|
| A    | C   |       11|
| B    | C   |       13|
| B    | C   |       13|
```

How to do that using Panda Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and filter by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) only selected columns in list and test of both `True`s per rows by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df1 = df[df[['Start','End']].isin(start_end_list).all(axis=1)]
```

Another idea is test both columns separately by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and chain masks by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df1 = df[df['Start'].isin(start_end_list) & df['End'].isin(start_end_list)]
```

---

```
print (df1)
  Start End  Distance
0     A   B        10
1     A   C        11
3     B   C        13
```

**Detail1**:

```
print (df[['Start','End']].isin(start_end_list))
   Start    End
0   True   True
1   True   True
2   True  False
3   True   True
4   True  False
5   True  False

print (df[['Start','End']].isin(start_end_list).all(axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

**Detail2:**

```
print (df['Start'].isin(start_end_list))
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
Name: Start, dtype: bool

print (df['End'].isin(start_end_list))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: End, dtype: bool

print (df['Start'].isin(start_end_list) & df['End'].isin(start_end_list))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

EDIT: For repeat rows add [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) by only stable algo `mergesort` and last create default index by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`

```
df2 = pd.concat([df1, df1]).sort_index(kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
  Start End  Distance
0     A   B        10
1     A   B        10
2     A   C        11
3     A   C        11
4     B   C        13
5     B   C        13
```

Comment: I just edited the question, what if I have a repeated value in the start_end_list and have to extract the distance accordingly to it? (like is shown in the edited question)